# Camel SEDA queue messages before sending Spring

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, ems

I am sending messages after processing via EMS using Camel. I have something like the following in Spring:

```
<route>
    <from uri="startMessage"/>
    <to uri="processMessage"/>
    <to uri="sendMessage"/>
</route>
<--! More routes below -->
```

The problem is I have around 8 of these routes and I want to queue the messages before sending each via "sendMessage" on EMS.

At the moment I have:

```
<route>
    <from uri="startMessage"/>
    <to uri="processMessage"/>
    <to uri="seda:sendMessage"/>
</route>
<--! More routes below -->
```

But the "seda" part does not work as expected. The message never gets sent as it does previously.

Any suggestions for this use case would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you need to listen to that seda queue somewhere.
The following route will enable seda staging on your first example.

```
<route>
    <from uri="startMessage"/>
    <to uri="processMessage"/>
    <to uri="seda:sendMessage"/>
</route>

<route>
    <from uri="seda:sendMessage"/>
    <to uri="sendMessage"/>
</route>
```